# HTML iframe - Double Scrolling Bars

Tags: html, css

I set up a iframe like below

```
<iframe src="http://www.bbc.com/" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>
```

CSS

```
iframe { overflow:hidden;
         min-height:600px}
```

2 horizontal scrolling bars appear, 1 is at the iframe and the other is at the browser.

I want to get rid of the bar at iframe, I try

```
<iframe src="yahoo.com" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Then the scrolling bar at the iframe disappeared, and the problem is I cannot see anything at the bottom of BBC website!

I could increase `min-height` to greater number to cover entire length of BBC's page, but sometimes the page is very short and I'll get a huge white space at the bottom!  So that increase the `min-height` is not a good practice.

How can I remove the scrolling bar at the iframe and use the browser's scrolling bar to navigate the page up and down?

Thank you!

Comment: I use javascript to set the height of the iframe.

Comment: Thank you very much, Tony! Can you please explain more how to use javascript to set the height of the iframe iframe?

Comment: `var h = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;document.getElementById("myIframe").style.height = (h-200) + "px";`  ps.200 is the height that don't include in iframe.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of doing this. There's jQuery solutions too. This will help you get started:

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/voqubo/1

CSS

```
body,html {padding:0;margin:0;height:100%;}

html {overflow-y:auto}

.embed-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.embed-container iframe,
.embed-container object,
.embed-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='embed-container'><iframe src='http://www.bbc.com/' style='border:0'></iframe></div>
```

Comment: BootstrapTheme, Thank you very much for your help!  It looks amazing, the scrolling bar from iframe is gone!  I wonder why we need to have `.embed-container object` and `.embed-container embed`? I don't see `object` and `embed` in your code.  Thanks

Comment: Just in case you do, if you're not using it, remove. If you found this answer is useful, select it.

Comment: Hi BootstrapTheme, I try it and it works well.  However, if I add 2 more `<div>s`, one is on the top and the other is on the left, then the scrooling bar at iframe appears! [http://jsbin.com/huviko/1]  Do you have any idea?

Comment: Of course it would, the width and height are 100% of the view port, if other things are consuming that space then the container of the iframe needs to have negative margin or other things, such as jQuery. The thing to do is to make a new question with same code and a jSBin or Fiddle. I

Comment: Thank you, BoostrapTheme! I open a new question located at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286626/2-navigator-bars-by-using-iframe].  Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<iframe 
    src="http://maroof.sa/Business/GetStamp?bid=203783" 
    style=" width: auto; height: 250px; overflow-y:hidden;  "  
    frameborder="0" 
    seamless='seamless' 
    scrollable="no">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While your code snippet may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how your code snippet works improves its long-term value.