# 2 navigator Bars By Using Iframe

Tags: html, css

I have 3 DIVs, one is on the top width 100% and other 2 are below.

Below, I have 1 DIV is on the left and other is on the right and it contains an iframe.  Because the page in the iframe is too long, it causes a navigator bar at iframe appears along with another navigator bar appearing at the browser!

I try `overflow-y:hidden;`, it doesn't help.  Then I try `scrolling="no"`, the scrolling bar at the iframe disappear, but I scroll to the bottom of the page.

Do you have any idea how to get rid of the scrolling bar at the iframe and can use the browser's navigator bar to see the bottom page?  Thank you!

http://jsbin.com/jajod/1

HTML

```
<div class="top">hthe</div>
<div class="left">nhnn ngbgw b bw</div>
<div class='right'><iframe src='http://javascript.about.com/od/ajax/a/ajaxasyn.htm'  style='border:0'></iframe></div>
```

CSS

```
    .top{
        float:left; 
        width:100%; 
        height:230px; 
        background-color:green;
    }
    .left{
        float:left; 
        width:30%; 
        background-color:red
    }
    .right{   
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .right iframe{
        position: absolute;
        top:230px;
        left: 30%;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
        float:left;
        overflow-y:hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ---

```
<div class="top">hthe</div>
<div class="left">nhnn ngbgw b bw</div>
<div class='right'><iframe src='http://javascript.about.com/od/ajax/a/ajaxasyn.htm' 
scrolling="no" style="border:0;overflow:hidden;display:block; 
position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%"></iframe></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/leowebdev/tm38f245/

Comment: Thank you, LeoWebDev!, but it doesn't work. We couldn't scroll to the bottom of the page.

Comment: so you wanna scroll without the scroll bars ? or you want to show the iframe window but displaying the bottom of the page ? you'll have to use jquery to change the offset.top >> search for jquery .offset().top;