# Is there a way to prevent double scrolling bars using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

**This question appears to be a duplicate that was unanswered or similar to** [HTML iframe - Double Scrolling Bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25248509/html-iframe-double-scrolling-bars).

**I would like to know how to remove the scrolling bar of the iframe and use the browser's scrolling bar to navigate the page up and down?**

```html
<html>
    <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0;">
        <div style="width:100%;height:50px; background-color:red;"></div>
        <iframe frameBorder="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="http://www.mynewplace.com/apartments-for-rent/st-paul-mn"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to make css('overflow','hidden') for Iframe, hope it will work

Comment: @syms that would hide all scrollable content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `scrolling="no"` for `iframe`

```
iframe { overflow:hidden;}
```

HTML:

```
<iframe frameBorder="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;" scrolling="no" src="http://www.mynewplace.com/apartments-for-rent/st-paul-mn"> 
  </iframe>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that i am unable to view the content of the iframe tag, unless I extend the height of the parent, which can vary.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up height of all parent element to 100% (so HTML and BODY tag) and then put height of iframe to calc(100% - 50px)

```css
html, body{height: 100%;}
```

```html
<html>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0;">
  <div style="width:100%;height:50px; background-color:red;"></div>
  <iframe frameBorder="0" style="width:100%;height:calc(100% - 50px);" src="http://www.mynewplace.com/apartments-for-rent/st-paul-mn">
  </iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't forget to make the iframe `display:block` or have a non-baseline vertical-align setting, or this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

try to set height by jvascript,
example:

```
<iframe id="test" FRAMEBORDER=0
  src="form.jsp"
  style="width: 100%"
  onload="this.height=document.body.scrollHeight">
</iframe>
```